# How do I calculate the maximum separation between a chord and arc when I only know the length of each?

Tags: geometry

[image: SegmentArcChordQuery]

If I know the length of a chord and I know the length of an arc that both have the same starting and ending points (A and B), how do I calculate the maximum separation between them? (D and D1)

What is the radius of the circle that defines the arc (AC or BC)?

and what is the contained angle (ACB)?

I'm hoping to receive more than one different answer, as I may not understand the first!

Comment: Hint: The length of the chord is $2 r \sin (\theta/2)$ the length of the arc is $r\theta$ and the distance CD is $r\cos(\theta/2)$

Comment: It is a pure math question. It is better to move it.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Be sure that the hint-complete answer given in a comment removes any motivation for you to learn write in $\LaTeX$ and solve by yourself so simple elementary mathematical problems.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, the length of the chord $L_c$, the length of the arc $L_a$, and the distance $L_{CD} = \lVert C D \rVert$ are
$$\begin{aligned}
L_c &= 2 r \sin \varphi \\
L_a &= 2 r \varphi \\
L_{CD} &= r \cos \varphi \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $r$ is the radius and $\theta = 2 \varphi$ is the angle of the circular arc (so $\varphi$ is half the arc angle, $\varphi = \theta/2$).  The maximum separation $h = \lVert D D^\prime \rVert$ is
$$h = r - L_{CD} = r ( 1 - \cos\varphi )$$

The key to solve this problem is to realize that the ratio of the two known values
$$\frac{L_c}{L_a} = \frac{\sin\varphi}{\varphi} = \operatorname{Sinc}(\varphi)$$
where $\operatorname{Sinc}$ refers to the [Sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function), which does not have a simple inverse, but you can find $\varphi$ numerically.

I recommend using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve $L_c/L_a = y = \operatorname{Sinc}(\varphi)$ for $\varphi$. Within $0 \lt \varphi \lt 4 \pi$ (corresponding to $0 \lt \theta \lt 2 \pi$), there are three discontinuities where the derivative is zero (four if you count $\varphi = 0$): $\varphi \approx 4.49341$, $\varphi \approx 7.72525$, and $\varphi \approx 10.90412$.  This means that there are four different ranges for the possible solutions $\varphi$, with $\operatorname{Sinc}(\varphi)$ being bijective and monotonic within each range.  ($0 \lt \varphi \lt 4.49341$ is monotonically decreasing, $4.49341 \lt \varphi \lt 7.72525$ is monotonically increasing, $7.72525 \lt \varphi \lt 10.90412$ is monotonically decreasing, and $10.90412 \lt \varphi \lt 4 \pi$ is monotonically increasing.)

In this case, the function $f(\varphi) = \sin(\varphi)/\varphi - y$, and its derivative is $f^\prime(\varphi) = \cos(\varphi)/\varphi - \sin(\varphi)/\varphi^2$.  Given an initial guess $\varphi_0$ within each of the aforementioned ranges, Newton's method iterates
$$\varphi_{n + 1} = \varphi_n - \frac{f(\varphi_n)}{f^\prime(\varphi_n)} = \varphi_n - \varphi_n \frac{y \varphi_n - \sin(\varphi_n)}{\sin(\varphi_n) - \varphi_n \cos(\varphi_n)}$$
until a sufficiently good approximation is found.

When $\varphi$ is known, you can solve $r$ from $L_a = 2 r \varphi$, i.e. $r = L_a / (2 \varphi)$.  At that point, you have the variables you need to calculate $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming $y>0$, if we look for the solution of
$$y=\frac {\sin(t)} t$$ when $y >0.128375$, using Taylor expansion, we have
$$y=1-\frac{t^2}{6}+\frac{t^4}{120}-\frac{t^6}{5040}+\frac{t^8}{362880}+O\left(t^{10}
  \right)$$

Using series reversion,
$$t=\frac{\sqrt{6(1-y)}}{112000}\left(138417-39231 y+16011 y^2-3197 y^3+\cdots \right)$$ Trying for $y=0.5$, the above formula gives $$t=\frac{139891 \sqrt{3}}{128000}\approx 1.89296$$ while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, is $1.89549$.